# Книги по интерфейсам

Tags: книги, сеть

Учусь в универе на 2ом курсе. Есть дисциплина которая называется типовые интерфейсы и сетевое оборудование. Пропустил очень много пар, можете подсказать какие книжки можно почитать чтобы понять о чем там идет речь. P.S. лекции не вариант=)совсем непонятно там

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А соответствующие книжки спасут "отца русской демократии" от провала на экзамене?
Лекции как раз именно вариант, поскольку препод давал объяснения в необходимом объеме для сдачи экзамена. В книгах будет еще более "непонятно" - ибо у Вас отсутствует "основа" понимания данных вещей, которая и давалась на первых лекциях.
Можно посоветовать, например, такое:
1) [Сетевые средства UNIX](http://uneex.ru/static/AltDocs_unix_base_admin/ch04.html)
2) [Сетевой интерфейс](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81)
3) [Сетевой интерфейс](http://www.opennet.ru/base/net/iproute2_cebka.txt.html)
ну и далее...
Надеюсь использование Гугл не противоречит религии, как противоречит ей хождение на занятия? :)